# Error: It is not supported to use minDist with activeOffsetX or activeOffsetY

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-modalize

is there any fix for this now?

https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize/issues/374

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the react-native-modalize version to "^2.0.8" and the error stopped showing for me

Try running: `yarn upgrade react-native-modalize`